# What kind of skull is this-I found it on the beach in Cape May

Tags: species-identification, zoology, mammals, bone

I am hoping someone can help identify this skull! We found it on the beach in Cape May. The skull size is about 4 inch in length. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: [www.boneid.net](http://www.boneid.net) provides a great searchable database of identified bones

Comment: Eyes at sides, have incisors and molars. This is a herbivore and not a sea mammal. According to the large incisors and placement of the teeth, I think it's a rodent.

Comment: Harun, Do you know what kind of rodent it might be?

Comment: Possibly a gopher.